# Laravel .htaccess file setup?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, deployment

I want to deploy a laravel project but I get an internal server error 500 all the time, when I click on some link/route. I strongly believe it's the `.htaccess` file. The default file looks like this and I have no idea how I need to modify it.

On my ftp server I set it up like this:
The webspace is connected to **/raidsystem/public_html/**
The `.htaccess` is inside the _public_html_ and the other folder is called '**lsapp**' which is in **/raidsystem/**, so it looks like this:

`/raidsystem/lsapp/`

`/raidsystem/public_html/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: show code of `index` file in public directory. And directory structure of your server

Comment: `<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));


require __DIR__.'/lsapp/vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/lsapp/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
`

Comment: `raidsystem/lsapp/vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: `raidsystem/public_html/index.php`
`raidsystem/public_html/.htaccess`

Webspace is connected to public_html

Answer (score 0):

> #### In your conditions

Your `index.php` file in `raidsystem/public_html/` needs to change

`require __DIR__.'/lsapp/bootstrap/autoload.php';`
**AND**
`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/lsapp/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: I get the following error then:

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/10/d694923868/htdocs/raidsystem/public_html/lsapp/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.2') in /homepages/10/d694923868/htdocs/raidsystem/public_html/index.php on line 24

My autoload.php btw is in /lsapp/vendor/autoload.php

And I changed to php 7.2 already on the providers control panel.

Comment: which laravel version you are using

Comment: Mine is 5.4 check if your `require()` method indicating to right directory/file.  Check `autoload` file in _bootstrap_ directory or this will be in _vendor_ directory of root.

Comment: This error only matters to correct file in correct location.

Comment: The autoload.php directs correct to `require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';` The autoload file is inside _lsapp/vendor_ Inside the _bootstrap_ I only have a cache folder and an _app.php_

Comment: And the _app.php_ says this `$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);`